# CSP with nonce under node.js application - Refused to apply inline style/script

Tags: node.js, express, google-chrome, content-security-policy

I'm trying to secure my website (built with node.js/express/npm) with correct CSP. I'm using npm helmet package and trying to configure CSP using nonce. I have tried to pass nonce in any possible way but I can't figure why Chrome is refusing to execute inline styles or scripts. A code example below:

```
// my app.js
// I generate a new random nonce value for every response.
    const nonce = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString("base64");

//configure CSP under helmet
    app.use(
    helmet.contentSecurityPolicy({
        useDefaults: false,
        directives: {
            defaultSrc: ["'self'"],
            connectSrc: ["'self'", ...connectSrcUrls],
            scriptSrc: ["'self'", "unsafe-inline", `nonce-${nonce}`, ...scriptSrcUrls],
            styleSrc: ["'self'", ...styleSrcUrls],
            workerSrc: ["'self'", "blob:"],
            objectSrc: [],
            imgSrc: [
                "'self'",
                "blob:",
                "data:",
                "https://res.cloudinary.com/dqcadja0y/",
                "https://images.unsplash.com/"
            ],
            fontSrc: ["'self'", ...fontSrcUrls],
        },
    })
);

//I pass nonce
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('home', { style: 'app', nonce: nonce });
});

//example of use in script e.g. mapbox
<script nonce="${nonce}" src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.2.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
```

error return from the console:

> Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following
> Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self'
> https://fonts.googleapis.com/ https://api.mapbox.com/
> https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/ https://fonts.googleapis.com/
> https://fonts.gstatic.com https://use.fontawesome.com/
> https://cdn.jsdelivr.net". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword or a
> nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note that
> hashes do not apply to event handlers, style attributes and
> javascript: navigations unless the 'unsafe-hashes' keyword is present.

I tried to look into documentation of express, helmet but I cant figure this out. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an inline style, and as the error message says you have to either add 'unsafe-inline' or a nonce. When it is a  tag you could also use a hash. If it is a style attribute (style="...">) the hash won't work, and likely not nonce either in most cases. Note that you have set 'unsafe-inline' for script-src, but you also have to be more permissive in style-src. An alternative is of course to move styles from inline to a separate file located in one of the style location you have allowed.